# Dexie doesn't return Class type on query, when using mapToClass

Tags: typescript, indexeddb, dexie

I am experimenting with using Dexie for a project, and I am trying to use both Typescript and the `.mapToClass` functionality in tandem.  When trying to implement the example at [Dexie: Typescript](https://dexie.org/docs/Typescript), I am getting some mixed results. Here's an example of what I mean:

#### The setup

**models/Entry.ts**

```js
export default abstract class Entry<T extends {}> {
  constructor(props: T, hiddenPropKeys?: string[]) {
    // merge props with instance to initialize all props from the interface/class
    Object.assign(this, props);

    // programmatically adding non-serializable keys
    hiddenPropKeys?.forEach((key) =>
      Object.defineProperty(this, key, { writable: true }),
    );
  }
}
```

**models/Friend.ts**

```js
import db from '../db';
import Entry from './Entry';

interface IFriend {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  relationship: string;
}

const table = db.friends;
type Type = IFriend; // shorthand, mainly for the static method

// doing this instead of having to iterate over every interface member again, as part of the class 
interface Friend extends Type {
  addresses: string[]
}
// eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare
class Friend extends Entry<Type> {
  constructor(params: Type) {
    super(params, ['addresses']);
  }

  save() {
    /* do some stuff to process the Friend */
    return table.put(this);
  }

  getAddresses() {
    /* some method to grab addresses and store them locally */
    this.addresses = ['123 Main St', '55 Foo Bar Ln'];
  }

  // static helper basically do a db lookup
  // I was thinking to add a caching layer here as well
  // it won't stop you from attempting to search by non-indexed fields, but neither will Dexie
  static find<T extends keyof Type>(
    key: T,
    value: Required<Type>[T] | Required<Type>[T][],
  ) {
    const query = table.where(key);
    return value instanceof Array ? query.anyOf(value) : query.equals(value);
  }
}

// the Dexie sugar
table.mapToClass(Friend);

export default Friend;
```

**db.ts**

```js
import Dexie, { Table } from 'dexie';
import { IFriend } from './models/Friend';

export class DataBase extends Dexie {
  friends!: Table<IFriend, number>;

  constructor() {
    super('Projector');
    this.version(1).stores({
      friends: '++id, &name'
    });
  }
}

const db = new DataBase();
```

#### The problem

**Main.ts**

```
...
const friend = await Friend.find('name', 'Frank').toArray();
console.log(friend instanceof Friend); 
// true <<< good

friend.getAddresses(); 
// TS: Property 'getAddresses' does not exist on type 'IFriend' <<< the issue
...
```

For some reason, the results from `toArray()` are coming back as advertised via `mapToClass()`, but not typed correctly to be used with TypeScript. Is there any way to fix this?

#### Things I've tried

I tried to write a custom addon, but I don't think this does anything useful.

```js
db.Table.prototype.toArray = Dexie.override(
  db.Table.prototype.toArray,
  function (original) {
    return function () {
      return original
        .apply(this, arguments)

        // this would be dynamic, ideally, but i was just trying to get something to happen
        .map((entry) => entry as Friend); 
    };
  },
);
```

I can also just manually do something like this:

```js
const friends = await Friend.find('name', ['Fred', 'Bob']).toArray(f => f as Friend[]);
```

but that kind-of defeats the purpose.

I've also tried switching up the `Table` type to use `Friend` instead

```js
...
export class DataBase extends Dexie {
  friends!: Table<Friend, number>; // Class instead of interface

  constructor() {
    super('Projector');
    this.version(1).stores({
      friends: '++id, &name'
    });
  }
}
...
```

but that just throws errors when adding new rows, as the methods seem to get enumerated into the type, for some reason.

Thanks in advance, for any help

### Update:

If I change the table definition to use the class instead of the object interface:

```
export class DataBase extends Dexie {
  friends!: Table<Friend, Friend['id']>; // <<< using class instead

  constructor() {
    super('Projector');
    this.version(1).stores({
      friends: '++id, &name'
    });
  }
}
```

I lose the ability to `table.add()` with an `IFriend` object (which is kind-of ok), but it seems to always return the correct type. When I try to add via object after this change, it complains about the instance methods missing.

### Update2:

using `EntityTable<Friend, 'id'>` instead of `Table<Friend, number>` to define the data set fixes the issues from the first update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is addressed in dexie 4. See https://dexie.org/roadmap/dexie4.0#distinguish-insert--from-output-types

Install dexie@4 using `npm install dexie@next`.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same issue after the update. Is there updated documentation for dexie4? thanks again

Comment: I've added an update to the description of the issue. Let me know if that's what you had in mind.